# Why firewall-cmd can't list active ports on my local pc?

Tags: firewall, nmap

```
sudo nmap -p0-65535 127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-06 19:03 HKT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Not shown: 65525 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
143/tcp  open  imap
```

List ports with firewall-cmd.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-ports
```

No ports listed! How to get the same ports displayed with firewall-cmd as with nmap?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that these rules are defined based on the service rather than the port directly. Run `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all` and check if you have the listed services allowed on the correct zone. You can see in my example, that `ssh`, `dhcpv6-client` are allowed, which doesn't show the actual ports.

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources: 
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

If you want to see the ports for ssh, you can look at the rule for that service:

```
# cat /usr/lib/firewalld/services/ssh.xml
```

Comment: If the firewall is set to allow any traffic on all ports (no blocking rule) then whatever you do with firewall-cmd, you will never get the list of ports on which an application is listening.  Open/allowed/closed and filtered ports have specific meaning and are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
firewall-cmd --zone public --list-all | awk '/services/ { for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { print $i;system("grep -o port=.* /usr/lib/firewalld/services/"$i".xml") } }'
```

A solution utilizing firewalld-cmd and awk would be as above. Run the firewall-cmd --zone public --list-all command to get the list of services and then pull out the services line with awk. Looping through each service on this line (space delimited word) we execute a grep command looking for any ports in `/usr/lib/firewalld/services/<service name>.xml`

Note that there are risk associated with command injection when executing the awk system function.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to get see the permanent configuration,

add `--permanent` otherwise you will get the running configuration and the permanent open ports won't show:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all --permanent
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: to answer direcly to the question, firewall-cmd cannot list active ports (as reported by nmap) because it is not its function (i.e. listing on which ports some applications/services are listening or not). Its function is to block or allow trafic on specific ports and as such, it can list the ports it blocks or allows (only).

Blocked/Allowed ports are not the same as open/closed ports as seen by nmap.

(*end of edit*)

**nmap open ports definition**: an application (a.k.a. daemon or server or service) is listening on that port on the host.

This definition assumes that no firewall in between the application and the scanner is blocking the trafic on the ports applications are listening on.

```
Application  <->  firewall       <->    Scanner 
(netstat)         (firewall-cmd)        (nmap)
----------------------------------------------------
ssh : 22           no rule              22 is open
http: 80           no rule              80 is open
```

If your firewall is wide open (no blocking rule), nmap will report all applications listening on all ports. But if you query your firewall you will get nothing because no rule is in place (that is weak protection).

You would likely see the same result (as reported by nmap) by asking directly to your host what are the applications listening on which port with a command like:

`netstat -a`

However, if you configure your firewall with a rule that blocks everything, your nmap scanner won't be able to see any of those applications listening (on some ports). If you query your firewall you will also see that no port is open (nothing will be reported). Still, `netstat -a` will report listening applications.

```
Application  <->  firewall       <->    Scanner 
(netstat)         (firewall-cmd)        (nmap)
----------------------------------------------------
ssh : 22          [X]                   22 is filtered
http: 80          [X]                   80 is filtered
```

Finally, if you configure your firewall to let only those ports your applications are listening on open, then you will see the same open ports via `nmap`, `netstat` and by querying your firewall...

```
Application  <->  firewall       <->    Scanner 
(netstat)         (firewall-cmd)        (nmap)
----------------------------------------------------
ssh : 22          [O]                   22 is open
http: 80          [O]                   80 is open
```

Comment: This is not a direct answer to why firewall-cmd can not do it.

Comment: @number9 : I believe with this edit, there is a direct answer to why firewall-cmd cannot do it.